# React Stateless components - performance and PureRender

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs, ecmascript-6, stateless

Everyone says that it uses `stateless` components will improve application performance. I noticed, however, that the use of stateless component in the wrong place can really **reduce** application performance.

This happens because the stateless components, render always, even if the properties **have not changed**.

In the case of `stateful` components we can use `PureComponent`, `PureRenderMixin` or implement own `shouldComponentUpdate` - thanks it noticed a **big Increase** in application performance when compared to stateless components.

I wanted to ask if there is some way to implementation something like `pureRender` for stateless component?. I'm not interested in wrapping stateless component in  stateful components.

If this is not possible, so how is it really with **performance** in `stateless` components?

I prepared two simple examples, showing that what I wrote. Try change active button:

stateful PureComponent:

```js
class List extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.generateElements = this.generateElements.bind(this);
    this.changeActive = this.changeActive.bind(this);
    this.state = {
     active: 0
    }
  }
 generateElements(){
   let elements = [];
    for(let i = 0; i<=1000; i++){
     elements.push(<Element key={i} 
                  index={i}
                             active={this.state.active === i} 
                             changeActive={this.changeActive} /> )
    }
    return elements;
  }
  changeActive(index){
   this.setState({
     active: index
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
     <div>
        <div className="classButtons">
          {this.generateElements()}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Element extends React.PureComponent{
  render() {
  console.log('render');
    return(
      <button onClick={this.props.changeActive.bind(null, this.props.index)}
            className={this.props.active ? 'active' : null} >
       Element {this.props.index}
      </button>
    )

  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<List />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```css
button{
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
button.active{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react-dom.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Stateless component:

```js
class List extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.generateElements = this.generateElements.bind(this);
    this.changeActive = this.changeActive.bind(this);
    this.state = {
     active: 0
    }
  }
 generateElements(){
   let elements = [];
    for(let i = 0; i<=1000; i++){
     elements.push(<Element key={i} 
                  index={i}
                             active={this.state.active === i} 
                             changeActive={this.changeActive} /> )
    }
    return elements;
  }
  changeActive(index){
   this.setState({
     active: index
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
     <div>
        <div className="classButtons">
          {this.generateElements()}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const Element = ({changeActive, index, active}) => {
 console.log('render');
  return(
    <button onClick={changeActive.bind(null, index)}
            className={active ? 'active' : null} >
            Element {index}
    </button>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<List />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```css
button{
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
button.active{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react-dom.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Overusing `code markup` and **boldface** makes your post less clear, not more so.

Comment: You're right, thanks, I corrected post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I noticed, however, that the use of stateless component in the wrong
>   place can really reduce application performance.

Indeed. For complex components, you should avoid stateless components.

> Everyone says that it uses stateless components will improve
>   application performance

you miss one important part... **in Future**.

> I wanted to ask if there is some way to implementation something like
>   pureRender for stateless component?

No, not yet.

> If this is not possible, so how is it really with performance in
>   stateless components?

Components that implement `shouldComponentUpdate` will perform better.

---

See [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5677) my statements backed up by the React team. Two important quotes from there

> For complex components, defining shouldComponentUpdate (eg. pure
>   render) will generally exceed the performance benefits of stateless
>   components.

[Dan Abramov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/458193/dan-abramov):

> There are currently no special optimizations done for functions,
>   although we might add such optimizations in the future. But for now,
>   they perform exactly as classes.